# How To Comment Out XML <Tag> using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I would like to comment out a text like this:

```
<name>cranberry</name>
```

However, my script returns the output like this:

```
<!-- &lt;name&gt;cranberry&lt;/name&gt; -->
```

My Script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Comment

tree = ET.parse(r"C:\sample.xml") 
root = tree.getroot() 
comment = ET.Comment("<name>cranberry</name>")
root.insert(0,comment)
tree.write(r"C:\sample1.xml")
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't worked on this. Looking at docs, I suggest you add the node first, get handle to the newly inserted node and run .Comment method on it, save the tree.

Comment: It could be Minidom..as long as I don't have to install external libraries..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You are right. what I mean is, get a handle to existing node and run .comment on it. I assume every node is a subtree, so to say.

Comment: A quick peek at the minidom source shows that it indeed won't escape comment contents.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: I know what you meant, but it won't work. :-)

Comment: Actually, I cannot reproduce this, not on Python 2.7. What version of Python is this? Only the `html` write method would escape comments like that in 2.7.

Comment: I checked Python 2.6, and it indeed will escape regardless. Can you upgrade to Python 2.7 or install ElementTree as an external library?

Comment: @Martijn: I saw another post about commenting XML via Python (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764017/commenting-and-uncommenting-xml-via-python), though I don't understand what they are doing..Do you think this could apply to my case?

Comment: @user1027101: They are using `minidom`, you can reuse that. I am writing an answer, should be done in a minute or so.

Comment: @Martijn: Really? Yea, I was using Python 2.6. I will upgrade it to 2.7. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The older ElementTree library included in Python 2.6 does indeed XML-escape data in comments unconditionally:

```
$ python2.6 -c "from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET; print ET.tostring(ET.Comment('<'))"
<!-- &lt; -->
```

You have a few options:

- Upgrade to Python 2.7; it handles comment serialization correctly:

  ```
  $python2.7 -c "from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET; print ET.tostring(ET.Comment('<'))"
  <!--<-->
  ```
- Install the external [ElementTree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/elementtree/) library.
- Use the Minidom (not recommended, the DOM API is overly verbose):

  ```
  from xml.dom import minidom

  doc = minidom.parse(r"C:\sample.xml")

  comment = doc.createComment("<name>cranberry</name>")
  doc.documentElement.appendChild(comment)

  doc.writexml(r"C:\sample1.xml")
  ```

Comment: This is a fine answer; have a +1.